# what happens when executing `(read "[Red]") :: [Color]` under ghci?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am reading the subsection of [Real World Haskell Chapter 6 (typeclasses)](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html) about aninstance of `Read` for `Color`, which implements `readsPrec` function. I don't know what happens when I type `(read "[Red]") :: [Color]` in GHCi, getting a `[Red]` result.

For simplicity, I changed this implementation of the function a little, as shown below:

```
instance Read Color where
     readsPrec _ value = [(Red, drop (length "Red") value)]
```

Now, my confusion is: in GHCi, we can use the above as follows:

```
*Main> let readsPrec 2 "Red]" = [(Red, drop (length "Red") "Red]")]
*Main> readsPrec 2 "Red]"
       [(Red,"]")]
```

Why `readsPrec _ value = [(Red, drop (length "Red") value)]` return `[Red]` when executing `(read "[Red]") :: [Color]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interaction going on between two instances of `readsPrec`:

1. the `readsPrec` you defined for `instance Read Color`
2. the `readsPrec` defined by the Prelude for `instance Read [a]`

Let's call the `readsPrec` in #2 `readsPrecList`.

When evaluating

```
read "[Red]" :: [Color]
```

what first happens is the `readsPrecList` is called. That function gobbles up the leading square paren and calls your `readsPrec` with the input string "Red]". Your function drops the first three characters and returns back to `readsPrecList` with the value `Red` and input string set to "]". That function checks that the next character is a closing square bracket and returns back your value in a list - i.e. `[Red]`.

Why does evaluation begin with a call to `readPrecList`? Because you are asking `read` to create a list of something.

Why does `readsPrecList` call the `readsPrec` for the type `Color`? Because you asked `read` to create a list of `Color` values.

This is an example of type-directed dispatch - the instance of `readsPrec` called is determined by the type of the value being requested.

Comment: thank you! `readsPrecList` can not be found from `Text.Read` and I got a message **Not in scope: `readsPrecList`** when `:t readsPrecList`? what something do I miss? Thank you again!

Comment: I use `readsPrecList` as a way to refer the function in #2. It is the list instance of `readsPrec` - so I call it `readsPrecList` to distinguish it from the `readsPrec` you defined for `Color`.

Comment: This is what the`Read` instance for lists looks like [(link)](http://git.haskell.org/packages/base.git/blob/065aef8da36a16bb23f07b298ccd63ed2a64f7fe:/GHC/Read.lhs#l425)

Comment: user5402 I finished reading the `Read` in [link](http://git.haskell.org/packages/base.git/blob/065aef8da36a16bb23f07b298ccd63ed2a64f7fe:/GHC/Read.lhs#l425) , from your explanation, **`readsPrecList` call the `readsPrec`**, so `readsPrec` returns `[(Red,"]")]` to `readsPrecList` and then we will get the final result `[Red]` from `readsPrecList` , but after scanning the whole link page, I still don't know what function of the link is corresponding to your `readsPrecList`?

Comment: There is a default way a defining readsPrec in terms of the other Read class functions - see around line 202. This is too complex to explain in a comment box, so open up a new SO question and I'll respond there. In the mean time you can google "Haskell type class default implementation".

Comment: user5402 for getting more explanation, I submit a [How does readsPrec and the relative functions return ...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27465001/1054800), I hope you will answer it, thank you!