# How does readsPrec and the relative functions return [Red] for read "[Red]" :: [Color]

Tags: haskell

This question is a continuation of [what happens when executing `(read "[Red]") :: [Color]` under ghci?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27442288/1054800). From [user5402's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442926/1054800), I know that there is a very complex execution path for `read "[Red]" :: [Color]` , which includes `readsPrec` and `readsPrecList`. According to @user5402's comments, `readsPrecList` call the `readsPrec`, so `readsPrec` returns `[(Red,"]")]` to `readsPrecList` and then we will get the final result `[Red]` from `readsPrecList`. However, I still cannot understand what function of the link corresponds to his `readsPrecList` and its implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant definitions are available in [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html), and look like this:

```
read             :: (Read a) => String -> a
read s           =  case [x | (x,t) <- reads s, ("","") <- lex t] of
                         [x] -> x
                         []  -> error "Prelude.read: no parse"
                         _   -> error "Prelude.read: ambiguous parse"

reads            :: (Read a) => ReadS a
reads            =  readsPrec 0

instance  (Read a) => Read [a]  where
    readsPrec p      = readList

class  Read a  where
    readsPrec        :: Int -> ReadS a
    readList         :: ReadS [a]
    readList         = readParen False (\r -> [pr | ("[",s)  <- lex r,
                                                    pr       <- readl s])
                       where readl  s = [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex s] ++
                                        [(x:xs,u) | (x,t)    <- reads s,
                                                    (xs,u)   <- readl' t]
                             readl' s = [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex s] ++
                                        [(x:xs,v) | (",",t)  <- lex s,
                                                    (x,u)    <- reads t,
                                                    (xs,v)   <- readl' u]

readParen        :: Bool -> ReadS a -> ReadS a
readParen b g    =  if b then mandatory else optional
                    where optional r  = g r ++ mandatory r
                          mandatory r = [(x,u) | ("(",s) <- lex r,
                                                 (x,t)   <- optional s,
                                                 (")",u) <- lex t    ]
```

The implementation of `lex` is much too large to include here -- it lexes Haskell.

A longish piece of equational reasoning below traces the full evaluation. I assume the implementation of the `Read Color` instance is the derived one. Since the interest here is the connection between lists and non-lists, I elide the details of expanding and evaluating `reads` at the base type `Color`.

```
reads "[Red]" :: [([Color], String)]
= { definition of reads }
readsPrec 0 "[Red]"
= { definition of readsPrec @[Color] }
readList "[Red]"
= { definition of readList @Color }
readParen False (\r -> [pr | ("[",s)  <- lex r, pr <- readl s]) "[Red]"
    where readl  s = [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex s] ++
                     [(x:xs,u) | (x,t)    <- reads s,
                                 (xs,u)   <- readl' t]
          readl' s = [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex s] ++
                     [(x:xs,v) | (",",t)  <- lex s,
                                 (x,u)    <- reads t, 
                                 (xs,v)   <- readl' u]
= { definition of readParen }
(\r -> [pr | ("[",s) <- lex r, pr <- readl s] ++ mandatory r) "[Red]"
    where readl  s = [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex s] ++
                     [(x:xs,u) | (x,t)    <- reads s,
                                 (xs,u)   <- readl' t]
          readl' s = [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex s] ++
                     [(x:xs,v) | (",",t)  <- lex s,
                                 (x,u)    <- reads t, 
                                 (xs,v)   <- readl' u]
          mandatory r = [(x,u) | ("(",s) <- lex r,
                                 (x,t)   <- optional s,
                                 (")",u) <- lex t]
= { beta reduction }
[pr | ("[",s) <- lex "[Red]", pr <- readl s] ++ mandatory "[Red]"
    where {- same as before -}
= { evaluation of `mandatory "[Red]"` and `(++)` }
[pr | ("[",s) <- lex "[Red]", pr <- readl s]
    where {- same as before -}
= { lex "[Red]" = [("[", "Red]")] }
[pr | pr <- readl "Red]"]
    where {- same as before -}
= { there's a name for this kind of reduction, but I don't know it }
readl "Red]"
    where {- same as before -}
= { definition of readl }
[([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex "Red]"] ++
[(x:xs,u) | (x,t)    <- reads "Red]",
            (xs,u)   <- readl' t]
where
          readl' s = [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex s] ++
                     [(x:xs,v) | (",",t)  <- lex s,
                                 (x,u)    <- reads t, 
                                 (xs,v)   <- readl' u]
= { lex "Red]" = [("Red", "]")] plus evaluation of (++) }
[(x:xs,u) | (x,t)    <- reads "Red]",
            (xs,u)   <- readl' t]
where {- same as before -}
= { reads "Red]" = [(Red, "]")] }
[(Red:xs,u) | (xs,u) <- readl' "]"]
where {- same as before -}
= { definition of readl' }
[(Red:xs,u) | (xs,u) <- [([],t)   | ("]",t)  <- lex "]"] ++
                        [(x:xs,v) | (",",t)  <- lex "]",
                                    (x,u)    <- reads t, 
                                    (xs,v)   <- readl' u]]
where {- same as before -}
= { lex "]" = [("]", "")] }
[(Red:xs,u) | (xs,u) <- [([],"")] ++ []]
= { evaluation of (++) and the list comprehension }
[([Red],"")]
```

We can use this derivation as a building block for evaluating `read`, since that's your top-level question.

```
read "[Red]" :: [Color]
= { definition of read }
case [x | (x,t) <- reads "[Red]", ("","") <- lex t] of
    [x] -> x
    []  -> error "Prelude.read: no parse"
    _   -> error "Prelude.read: ambiguous parse"
= { reads "[Red]" = [([Red], "")] }
case [[Red] | ("","") <- lex ""] of
    [x] -> x
    []  -> error "Prelude.read: no parse"
    _   -> error "Prelude.read: ambiguous parse"
= { lex "" = [("", "")] }
case [[Red]] of
    [x] -> x
    []  -> error "Prelude.read: no parse"
    _   -> error "Prelude.read: ambiguous parse"
= { again there's a name for case reduction but I don't know it }
[Red]
```

Comment: In implementation `read`, `("","") <- lex t` is must? I got the same result using my own definition `read' s =  case [x | (x,t) <- reads s] of ... ` without `("","") <- lex t`. what I miss?

Comment: @abelard20008 Compare `read "[Red]garbagehere"` with `read' "[Red]garbagehere"`.